# mysql. Запрос вроде верен, но не выдает данные из бд

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос в бд ошибок не выдает, но ничего не возвращает.

Comment: ´is NULL`, ´=NULL` всегда FALSE.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно писать `.....AND operatormessage IS NULL`, т.к. что-то сравнивать с `NULL` нельзя. Это ничто. Даже если сообщение пустое - оно есть и оно пустое, а не ничто.

На ознакомление:

- http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Working_with_NULL.html
- http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Problems_with_NULL.html